# httpClient.SendAsync throws Unspecified GSS failure

Tags: docker, .net-core, httpclient

I am using .NET Core 3.1
Here is a code that I am using:

```
        CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
        credentialCache.Add(new Uri(URL), "NEGOTIATE", new NetworkCredential(USER, PASSWORD, DOMAIN));

        using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            handler.Credentials = credentialCache;

            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), REQUEST_URL);

                HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;

                Console.Write(response.ToString());
            }
        }
```

It works corrent on my windows machine but crushes when is launched on linux docker container:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Cannot find KDC for realm "DOMAIN_NAME").)
> ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090020): GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information(Cannot find KDC for realm "DOMAIN_NAME").
> at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(String package, Boolean isServer, NetworkCredential credential)
> at System.Net.NTAuthentication.Initialize(Boolean isServer, String package, NetworkCredential credential, String spn, ContextFlagsPal requestedContextFlags,ChannelBinding channelBinding)
> at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithNtAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, ICredentials credentials, Boolean isProxyAuth, HttpConnection connection, HttpConnectionPool connectionPool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at OurHomeServer.Log.LoggingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /src/OurHomeServer/Log/LoggingHandler.cs:line 35
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)

It works when I use curl request in container's shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added following line to my Dockerfile

```
RUN apt install -y mc sudo syslog-ng realmd gss-ntlmssp
```

and now it works!!

Comment: I suppose "mc" and "sudo" are not required to fix the issue, and that it is fixed by adding "realmd" and "gss-ntlmssp"

Comment: Saved the day! For anyone using a virtual machine, installing directly on the server fixes the issue (as you'd expect).  For our Red Hat, and derivatives, friends:  `sudo yum install -y realmd gssntlmssp` does the trick!